# best way to change screen content in android apps

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

What is the best way to develop an android app with multiple screen content,
changing it with an drawer layout like the picture. **How can I do that?** By using 
fragments with one activity and change each fragment by old fragment, or choose another technique?

Now i'm using one activity and replacing fragments.

[image: drawer layout]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are doing it correctly.

Comment: just adjust your layout such that it doesn't take half of the screen. This will leave you very little space to show fragment. And if you agree then I will provide the same in answer so that you can mark the question solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the format of all the screens is the same, with essentially the same layout.  Then you would only need **one fragment** that is updated based on which item in the drawer was selected.

If the screens are different then the original approach with multiple fragments and one activity is recommended.